# Animate width toggle from right to left in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to slide a hidden (`display:none`) div block from right to left using jQuery. It should appear when a user hovers on this block. Here's code:

```
$('.wrapper').hover(function () {
    $(this).children('.item').stop(true, true).animate({width:'toggle'}, 400);
});
```

This code works fine, but it slides from left to right, and I want it to slide from right to left. How can I 'reverse' it?

Comment: How you want to fire `hover` event while it `display` is `none`?

Comment: @Mohammad I would deduce that the `.item` has `display: none`, and the `.wrapper` is visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animation makes `width` of the element change and when it is positioned in a usual manner, it gets shrinked to the left side (think of it this way: where will your block end up if it get 50% `width`?). You can position the `div` in another way, say with `float: right;` and in this case it will be shrinked to the right side.

Here's a snippet that illustrates this:

```js
window.toggle = function() {
 jQuery(".toggledOne, .toggledAnother").stop(true, true).animate({width:'toggle'}, 400);
}
```

```css
.wrapper,
.toggledOne,
.toggledAnother {
    width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    height: 2em;
}
.toggledOne,
.toggledAnother {
    height: 1em;
}
.toggledOne {
    background-color: red;
}

.toggledAnother {
    float: right;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="window.toggle();">click me</a>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="toggledOne"></div>
    <div class="toggledAnother"></div>
</div>
```